Prevent OPPO Find from switching on due to alarm
I used to own a OnePlus branded phone which had the hardware to 'wake on alarm', and there was a software switch in settings to turn it off.
I have looked for a similar software switch in my Oppo Find's ColorOS and I haven't seen one.
Is this possible?
